# Making a hosts file group into an input in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that calls an API. I have a `delegate_to: localhost`.

I want to run my playbook "against" every host in a group `Linux`.

I want the API call to do 2 things.

1. I want it to run once for every host in the `Linux` group
2. For every run, it should have a different host IP/hostname as the input

`linux` looks like:

```
[linux]
10.234.0.13
10.234.0.12
```

I run my like this: `ansible-playbook -i linux my_playbook`

How do I make the inventory group an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when ansible executes on the remote host it collects some meta data of the hosts. One of the meta data is ip address. The meta data is called ansible facts. There is an ansible fact to get the ip address

```
ansible_default_ipv4.address
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work for linux. Do you know if there is a similar variable for windows?

Comment: should be available. I don't have any windows server configured so can't check. You can run the below command that will list all the facts available. ansible <hostname> -m setup